# How to animate pictures to create a video?

Tags: macos, cocoa, video

I am looking to create a software for Mac that will take a set of pictures, a picture arrangement like the example below, and let the user **output a video that has each picture animating in to form the picture arrangement.**

[image]

I am looking for pointers to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to create an [electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) app.

It's pretty easy to animate photos like that on the html5 canvas, and you can save the exported video with something like [CCapture.js](https://github.com/spite/ccapture.js/)

See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jacobev/7t2hmL58/) for a simplified example with a basic animation and saving the video as webm:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var
    imgNW = new Image(),
    imgNE = new Image(),
    imgSE = new Image(),
    imgSW = new Image(),
    canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var fps = 30;

  var animation_offset = 0;

  var frameRequestID;

  imgNW.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  imgNE.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  imgSE.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  imgSW.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

  imgNW.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/po6Bma2.png';
  imgNE.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/WT75J7k.png';
  imgSE.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/pvDnwSD.png';
  imgSW.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/BYXjccx.png';


  function draw() {
    capturer.capture(canvas);
    if (animation_offset <= 210) {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
      ctx.fillStyle = "white";
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      var coord = animation_offset - 200;
      var invCoord = 420 - animation_offset;

      ctx.drawImage(imgNW, coord, coord);
      ctx.drawImage(imgNE, invCoord, coord);
      ctx.drawImage(imgSE, invCoord, invCoord);
      ctx.drawImage(imgSW, coord, invCoord);

      animation_offset += 1; //effectively adjusts the speed.  smaller numbers = slower movement

      frameRequestID = requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    } else {
      console.log("done!");
      capturer.stop();
      capturer.save();
      cancelAnimationFrame(frameRequestID);
    }
  }



  var capturer = new CCapture({
    format: 'webm',
    verbose: true,

  });
  capturer.start();

  draw();

}, false);
```